# SMS / Messages / iMessage alternative for all platforms?

Tags: chat, sms

Been having trouble with Apple's iMessage / Messages.app / SMS system.  I work between several Apple devices/computers and some Windows and Linux systems.  The problem I have is two fold: 1) Apple is simply a pain in the butt as far as authentication goes on multiple devices that work on multiple networks and 2) synchronization between everything doesn't always work reliably and is not even an option on Windows and Linux.

***Are there any cohesive SMS messaging options that work on all platforms and have a strong UI/UX?***

I would prefer to use my existing phone number that is tied into the iMessage system and would need to continue to work with that, but additionally would then also work with other platforms as well.

I am NOT interested in non-SMS platforms such as Signal or Telegram since they don't offer SMS interoperation.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? My firm pretty much runs on Apple iMessage and we have no issues with relatively high volume.

Comment: First, when using it on laptops that change network locations frequently I have issues with it requiring re-login (at least weekly). I have sync issues where it will not sync up quickly enough and I miss messages when changing. I'd also like to be able to use it on Windows and Linux workstations so that we can have ubiquitous SMS.